# PrimeFaces custom inputMask with multiple optional characters

Tags: primefaces

So I have this input that follows the following format and constraints : 'CC-NNNNNNN'  (C: letter, N: digit) the second letter is optional and all but the first digit are optional. Here are some examples to help you clarify things :
B-1231 || BJ-32 || W-1234567 
After some research on `<p:inputmask>` the only thing I could find for optionnal characters is `?` which marks all characters that come after it as optional, and there is also another problem if I use this mask `<p:inputMask value="#{antecedentView.cin}" mask="a?a-9999999" />` and I type "B-1234" it give `null` as a result. So to my understanding it accepts either the full input or the input without the optional characters.
So my question is there any way to do this with `<p:inputmask>` ? if not what method do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `p:inputText` with a `p:keyfilter` and a Regular expresion

```
<p:inputText>
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,}/"/>
</p:inputText>
```

that input will accept any string that starts with 1 or 2 letters followed by a dash followed by one or more digits